# typeerror: 'undefined' is not a function even when using jQuery.noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I keep getting TypeError for the Handlebars.compile() call. I tried adding jQuery.noConflict() to various places as suggested in some other posts but not luck.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Handlebars.compile('test')')
```

The code is:

```
$('.location-typeahead').typeahead(
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: states(),
  templates: {
    header: '<h4 class="location-typeahead-header">Title</h4>',
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('test')
  }
}
);
```

If I remove that whole "suggestion" templates parameter, my JS works fine.

Comment: doesn't sound like this is a jquery issue. have you included the handlebars script on your page? what do you get when you type `Handlebars` in your developer toolbar?

Comment: `> Handlebars
< HandlebarsEnvironment
COMPILER_REVISION: 4
Exception: function Exception(message, node) {
HandlebarsEnvironment: function HandlebarsEnvironment(helpers, partials) {
REVISION_CHANGES: Object
SafeString: function SafeString(string) {
Utils: Object
VERSION: "1.3.0"
VM: Object
create: function () {
createFrame: function (object) {
helpers: Object
log: function log(level, obj) { logger.log(level, obj); }
logger: Object
partials: Object
template: function (spec) {
__proto__: HandlebarsEnvironment`

Comment: Do you see `compile` in that list? I suspect you've included the runtime version, not the full version. Oh...or the error could be in your `test` template.

Comment: Ugh! I did use the runtime version. It works after I downloaded the other version. Thanks!

Comment: Made the same mistake.  It happens.  I'm glad you made the mistake too because I found my answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

You may have included the runtime version of Handlebars. You need to include the full version if you want to compile templates client-side.

Alternatively, you can pre-compile your templates -- then you only need the runtime.

Comment: Wish I looked this up before wasting an hour of my life.  I was also accidentally using the run-time.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't break your neck trying to do a simple template.  All of the documentation points to using Handlebars templates - but at the root level the 'suggestion' property of templates just has to be a function that accepts the data object & environment then returns the formatted string mark-up.

See the valid example below to do some slight tweaking to the format/layout - as long as you're returning the data you need in the data source this should work for the more advanced.

```
 //where data is the single data object returned
 //and environment is the typeahead context
 suggestion: function(data, env) {
    return "<p><strong>" + data.owner_name + "</strong> – " + data.name + "</p>";
 }
```